# Issue with Row selection when RowDisclosureEvent in tr:table is used with Trinidad

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, trinidad

I have a requirement of expanding/collapsing the row contents of a table using trinidad tags. Have tried with the following approach

Approach :

1. Added RowDisclosureEvent to the tr:table tag of my jspx
2. Defined facet:detailStamp for the inside table to be displayed
3. Handled RowDisclosureEvent in my MgdBean
4. I am using myfaces api and impl 2.1.17 , trinidad api/impl 2.1.0

Below are the code snippets for jspx and MgdBeans.

**Snippet of jspx**

```
<tr:table id="offers" var="offer" 
                    rendered="#{oMgdBean.offerList != null}"
                    value="#{oMgdBean.filteredOList}" varStatus="stat" 
                    binding="#{cpMgdBean.oTable}"
                    rowDisclosureListener="#{cpMgdBean.handleDisclosureEvent}"
                    width="100%">
                    <tr:column align="start"  styleClass="oLink">
                        <tr:panelHorizontalLayout rendered="#{offer.id != 'no_offer' and !empty offer.id}">
                                <tr:commandLink id="oLink" text="#{offer.name}" >
                                    <tr:setActionListener from="#{offer.name}"
                                        to="#{pageFlowScope.propName}" />
                                    <tr:setActionListener from="#{offer.id}"
                                        to="#{pageFlowScope.propId}" />
                                </tr:commandLink>                           
                            </tr:panelHorizontalLayout>
                        </tr:column>

                    <f:facet name="detailStamp" rendered="#{offer.id != 'no_offer' and !empty offer.id}">
                        <tr:panelHorizontalLayout halign="center">                                      
                            <tr:table styleClass="priorities" var="customerPriority" value="#{pageFlowScope.customerPriorityMap[offer.id]}" >
                                <!-- Display the data here -->
                            </tr:table>
                        </tr:panelHorizontalLayout>                         
                    </f:facet> 
                </tr:table>
```

**Snippet of MgdBean**

```
public void handleDisclosureEvent(org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.RowDisclosureEvent event) throws ServiceException{

        //get prop id from row
        RowKeySet AddedRowKeys = event.getAddedSet();

            List newList;
            Iterator rowKeysIter = AddedRowKeys.iterator();
            Product currentProp = null;
            while(rowKeysIter.hasNext()){

                //offerTable is instance of CoreTable   
                offerTable.getComponent().getRowCount().setRowKey(rowKeysIter.next());
                currentProp = (Product)offerTable.getComponent().getRowData();
                if(null != currentProp){
                    //check map for entry

                    if(pageFlowMap.containsKey(currentProp.getId())){
                        return;
                    }
                    newList = getData(currentProp);
                    pageFlowMap.put(currentProp.getId(), newList);

                }
            }
        }
```

Issues facing with current approach:

1. When I try to access the getRowData() of my table, selected RowData is coming as null. The getAddedSet does not seem to have the selected RowKeySet. (I think)
2. If I have 3 rows in my main table and I select first one to expand, all three rows are being expanded.

Any help would be appreciated.